# Moment() vs predefined Moment() date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am a bit confused on how the Moment functions work (such as `startOf()`, `weekday()`, etc).

My question is: how do I obtain the start of the week from a predefined date?

Consider these two calls on `9/21/16`:

```
moment().startOf('week') // Returns a moment object with date set to Sun Sep 18 2016 ...
```

vs

```
moment(new Date("9/21/16")).startOf('week') // Returns a moment object with date set to Wed Sep 21 2016 ...
```

Why don't these behave in the same way? The same is true when using `weekday(0)` instead of `startOf('week')`

Comment: `moment(new Date("9/21/16"))` doesn't make sense. The whole point of using a library is to help with parsing, so **don't** use the built–in Date parser (it's extremely unreliable, hence why so many parser libraries exist). Use `moment('9/21/16','M/D/YY')` which is also less to type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know that `moment(new Date("9/21/16")).startOf('week')` is returning `Wed Sep 21 2016`? Are you looking inside the returned object? If so, I think you're just seeing the input date. You should use `moment.format()` function to get the actual date:

```
// "September 18, 2016"
moment().startOf("week").format("LL");

// "September 18, 2016"
moment("9/21/16", "MM/DD/YY").startOf("week").format("LL");

// "September 18, 2016" on my system (not recommended)
moment(new Date("9/21/16")).startOf("week").format("LL");
```

Comment: Currently all the dates are stored in an array of objects with a bunch of other things. I would output the Moment objects to the console. Your second suggestion seems to work, I guess I'll just have to fine tune it so that it follows some formats like @Stijn has suggested

Comment: Yeah. I've updated my answer examples. Now it's my third suggestion. :) It works depending on the system as @Stijn said. My point is that you should use the format function to get the actual date, not looking inside the returned Moment object.

Answer (score 6):

You can't simply use the Date constructor with whatever date format you like. For example, on my system using Firefox, `new Date("9/21/16")` returns a Date object set to `1916-09-20T22:00:00.000Z`.

Use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, or even better, [parse your string with Moment itself](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
moment("9/21/16", "MM/DD/YY")
```

Comment: You can even use the `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);` syntax (which is however not popular at all, God knows why). And then there's the time zone issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't have much experience with dates and time zones in programming so I am definitely a newbie. Momentjs seemed interesting and easy to start off with for date creation or getting certain parameters

Comment: @MichaelMurata Dates and time zones are *very* complex topics. Sadly browser implementations differ in a lot of places, it's why libraries like Moment exist, so indeed it's a good idea to look into it.

Comment: @Stijn That's exactly what I've heard, which is why I thought using a library such as Moment would be a great starting place as opposed to going my own route with Date objects

Comment: @Stijn—dates and time zones aren't that hard, it's just that people don't take the time to learn the fairly simple rules associated with them. It doesn't help that the javascript Date was not well designed and lacks decent parsing and formatting (and implementations still have bugs, aren't standards compliant and are very inconsistent). It's fairly easy to write a parser, formatter and arithmetic functions—but of course there are good libraries around so no need for everyone to do that. ;-).